# Comparison isn't finding as true; but values sent to MsgBox show it should be

Tags: excel, vba

Here is a portion of my code..

```
'Loop through each SOP audit file
    For Each oFile In oFiles
        'MsgBox (RemoveLeadingZeroes(Split(oFile.Name, "-")(2)))
        'Loop through all SOP IDs stored in COL A
        For Each cel In SOPID
            MsgBox (RemoveLeadingZeroes(Split(oFile.Name, "-")(2)) & " : " & cel)
            'See if SOP ID in COL A matches SOP ID in Audit file name
            If RemoveLeadingZeroes(Split(oFile.Name, "-")(2)) = cel Then
                MsgBox ("Match found on SOP ID: " & cel)
            End If
        Next cel
    Next oFile
```

Here is a screenshot of the values being compared using the line...

```
MsgBox (RemoveLeadingZeroes(Split(oFile.Name, "-")(2)) & " : " & cel)
```

Why isn't the If() statement triggering the MsgBox saying there is a match if both values do in fact match? Is it treating one as a string and the other value as a range? Could that affect it?

[image]

Comment: because they're *obviously not* equal :) Consider `Trim` to remove leading/trailing whitespace while comparing strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Trim() to remove whitespace.